If the pullback of $\phi_1(x)=\exp_x(X_x)$, preserves the volume of the Riemannian manifod $M$, then $\operatorname{div}(X)=0$?
Let $M$ be an orientable compact Rimeannian manifold whithout boundary with volume form $\operatorname{vol}_M$. Take $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that if $\phi_t(x)$ is the flow of $X$ and $\phi_1:M\to M$ is such that
$$\phi_1^*\operatorname{vol}=\operatorname{vol},$$
does that mean that $\operatorname{div}(X)=0$?
I can ask that $\sup_x\lVert X_x\rVert$ to be arbitrarily small if needed. So it seems to me that in this case the divergence should be zero,
The fact that this map is volume preserving, we have that its Jacobian is 1. From here we have that this Jacobian is $$e^{\int_0^1\mathrm{div}X(\phi_S(x))}ds=1,$$
which means that $\int_0^1\mathrm{div}X({\phi_s(x)})ds=0$.
Since I can consider that $X$ is small, I may suppose that $\operatorname{div}X(\phi_s(x))$ does not change signals, so from the fact that integrates $0$, I conclude that $\operatorname{div}X(\phi_s(x))=0$ for $0\leq s\leq 1$. (Is that correct?)
Can I somehow conclude that $\operatorname{div}(X)\equiv 0$?

What if the flow defined by the vector field $X$ changes volumes for a while but returns to the original volumes at time $1$ ?

@AndreasBlass my question is if that can happen if I ask X to be sufficiently small

My comment applies to any $X$, even if it's small. You might have meant to fix an  $X$ and then consider, as your small vector fields, only multiples $\varepsilon X$ of that simgle $X$.

@AndreasBlass do you have an example?

I think this can only happen when the norm of X is a multiple of the injectivity radius

When you multiply X by epsilon, the new flow at 1 is the old one at $\epsilon$

That's why I suggested, in my last comment, that you might have meant to multiply a particular $X$ by $\epsilon$.  With that  reinterpretation of "sufficiently small", what you wrote earlier would become relevant.
